# Select multiple class with this context

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to select multiple element with `this` context such as

```
$(this,this.parent,'.other').removeClass('test').addClass('test2');
```

I want to select `this` element + `this` parent element + some other classes all togather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant call .parent() inside the selector, use:

```
 $(this).parent().add(this).add('.other').removeClass('test').addClass('test2');
```

Example:

```js
$("b").each(function() {
   $(this).parent().add(this).add('.other').removeClass('test').addClass('test2'); 
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
  }
.test2 {
  color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test">Parent <b class="test">this</b></p><i class="other test">Other</i>
```

Comment: Yes, working. at least this is better than writing multiple lines